# LWC - Remove Irrelevant Sections When Dragging in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have a draggable row in my Data Table that works great. I do however am seeing an extra section while dragging. It seems to be a transparent bit from whatever's above it. It may as well be by design in the Chrome Browser but I would love to know if there's a way to remove it.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

And here's a code snippet of my draggable row:

```
<tbody>
    <template for:each = {myList} for:item = "item" for:index="indexVar" >
        <tr key={item.Id} data-drag-id={item.Id} class="slds-hint-parent draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart={itemDragStart}>
        // ... some code goes here ...
    </template>
</tbody>
```

Appreciate any help and suggestions. Thanks!

**Updated:** Here is a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5kM.jpg).

Comment: When you say Data Table do you mean this one? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

Or are you building your own html table and applying slds styling to it?

Comment: Hi, @Arthlete. I'm using a custom one just like you mentioned in your last statement. Something like this [HTML in the playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/tlYE_njr4/6/). Is there a way to remove the extra section when dragging?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/tlYE_njr4/72/edit

Comment: Hi, @Arthlete. Actually, no. I'm not trying to remove the padding from my rows but trying to remove the extra section that looks faded when dragging the actual rows. Here is a [GIF](https://imgur.com/a/MKmJGa4).

Comment: Do you mean that you want the row to disappear as soon as you start dragging it?

Comment: I don't want the actual row I'm dragging to disappear but just the extra section that's attached to it, yes. I'm not sure if you could see clearly as it's kinda transparent but there are small parts of the upper row showing while I'm dragging it. I hope it's visible in the GIF. @Arthlete

Comment: Ohh do you mean the header, like "product", "description", "quantity", etc in your gif?

Comment: Take a look at the [GIF](https://imgur.com/a/34KKatH) I made. There's no sign of anything from the upper row when I am dragging. Try [this playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/tlYE_njr4/77/edit) and let me know if it's still not working correctly for you. If it is still giving you trouble then can you tell me the browser that you are using and your OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with placement of one of the *td*. I had a textarea there that wasn't aligned with others as it was using custom height through CSS, and as a result was very near the row that came before it. After applying CSS like *margin-top* and a few other things, the issue went away.